# Create a method with unknown number and type of arguments in java

Tags: java, primefaces, datatable, variadic-functions

I'm working with primefaces datatables, and at the same time I'm using Triple datastores (Jena TDB) instead of traditional databases. I'm going to create an object like primefaces showcase sample below;
public class Car {

```
    private String model;
    private int year;
    private String manufacturer;
    private String color;

    public Car(String model, int year, String manufacturer, String color) {
            this.model = model;
            this.year = year;
            this.manufacturer = manufacturer;
            this.color = color;
    }

    public String getModel() {
            return model;
    }

    public void setModel(String model) {
            this.model = model;
    }

    public int getYear() {
            return year;
    }

    public void setYear(int year) {
            this.year = year;
    }

    public String getManufacturer() {
            return manufacturer;
    }

    public void setManufacturer(String manufacturer) {
            this.manufacturer = manufacturer;
    }

    public String getColor() {
            return color;
    }

    public void setColor(String color) {
            this.color = color;
    }
```

}

here everything is clear and car object has definite arguments like model, year, ... however in my program based on user selection from the menu bar, I have to call quite different objects with various properties as arguments and do the same as shown in the showcase. I'm quite new in java and I really confused how can I solve this problem. 
As an example my program object could be a company with (Name, Address, Email, Tel ,... ) arguments, or it could be a Machine with quite different properties like (Name, Model, production date, Specs. and etc).

Thanks in advance for your responses.

Comment: What does the client (calling code) need to do with these objects?

Comment: 1. just sort object with different properties, and return them to the user. 2. Later on an algorithm uses these properties amount to select the most appropriate object according to the provided criteria. But for now I just want to call these objects in datatable and sort them!!

Comment: Have you thought about creating an interface that all of these objects can implement?  Then you could treat all objects as the same type.  Maybe it contains a `setField(String fieldName, Object value)` method and the object handles setting the field.

Comment: No I didn't. I'm going to try that! a new idea. Thanks Kevin!!

Comment: Let me know if you need any guidance. My blog in my profile contains my email.

Comment: I solved problem by using Primefaces dynamic column data tables, I did exactly like the primefaces showcase template just with one difference my column properties are arrays and in each row I use column.properties[rowId].

Comment: Now I'm going to solve next step which is selection of each table row, and display data regarding those rows in another page or maybe pop up window. Thank you Kevin. I just visited your blog. It is very useful and definitely I'm going to follow your blog :) Because as I told earlier I'm quite new in java and JSF and i'm learning all these step by step !!!

Answer (score 1):

Not exactly understood the explanation you have provided. I can give you one answer against your title: **Create a method with unknown number and type of arguments in java**

You can use Java args along with Object class.

```
package com.misc;

public class NNumberOfObj {
    public static void acceptNNumberOfAnyTypeofObjects(Object... args) {
        System.out.println("Total objects are: " + args.length);
        //Your further implementation goes here.
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String s = new String("Nikhil");
        Integer i = 10;
        Employee emp = new Employee(10, "Kunal");
        acceptNNumberOfAnyTypeofObjects(s, i, emp);
    }
}

class Employee {
    private int id;
    private String name;
    public Employee(int id, String name) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

Comment: please show how it is used and how it is implemented.

Comment: I know how varags work, I just think you should show that args is an array, and I think you still don't. +1 Anyway.

Comment: Hello, I just tried to show that args array can accept any number and type of arguments. Sorry if you were expecting something else.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. My problem exactly is here, you are aware of employee class and you are assigning id and name arguments for your employee, but in my model (ontology model) there are too many types of objects with quite different properties and arguments, and based on user selection i want to call them !! seems very strange but I don't know how to explain !!! Actually I used varargs but I've got any results. because later I have to define get set methods for different properties like you have done for id and name in employee class.

Comment: You can use Object as method argument, and then every time check object type using instanceof operator.